# PHP include file in subfolder

Tags: php, include, directory

I have two files `myMenu.php` and `myView.php`

This is my folder:

```
MyMainFolder
- myMenu.php
- MyViewFolder
--myView.php
```

Now i want to include `myMenu.php` into `myView.php` with `include(../myMenu.php);`

But this doesnt work. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Servers may not always be configured to use paths like that, you can use `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/path/to/file.filytype'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use it this way:

`include(__DIR__."/myMenu.php");`

Basically, you're taking the directory that the file you're processing is currently in (`__DIR__`), and you're telling it to look for that file in the same directory.

You could use this approach to include anything in different directories:
`include(__DIR__."/../_include/fileName.php")`

This would go back one directory from your currently processing file's location, then go in to the `_include` directory, and look for that file.